# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 2: invalid start byte

Tags: python

hello i'm trying a "python manage.py runserver" command in the cmd
but it returned me this eroor:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 2: invalid start byte"

on the position

> "socket.py", line 791, in getfqdn
> hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)

Here ist the original code in the editor:

```
def getfqdn(name=''):
     name = name.strip()
    if not name or name == '0.0.0.0':
        name = gethostname()
    try:
        hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
    except error:
        pass
    else:
        aliases.insert(0, hostname)
        for name in aliases:
            if '.' in name:
                break
        else:
            name = hostname
    return name
```

I have no idea how i can bypass this error since i am not sure if i understand the code.
(first time asking question, thanks for your help!)

Comment: This is a bug in Python; https://bugs.python.org/issue26227

Comment: thanks @BiOS!  that was really just a username problem, now the program works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `name` contains invalid characters the time it is given as argument to `gethostbyaddr()` in the `socket` module.

This is likely because your hostname actually does contains special characers. You may check for this by opening the Terminal or the Command Prompt and type in `hostname`

If you get something like this as a result:

```
računalo-codax
```

(The above is Croatian for "Codax-computer")

Then you need to change your computer name to make sure it does not contain any special characters like that `č`. Only plain letters `a-zA-Z` and numbers `0-9`, or a dash `-`.

Comment: That's dubious advice. Perhaps a better solution is to make sure you only use UTF-8 in your computer names because it's portable between platforms and increasingly becoming the _de facto_ standard for Unicode on the Internet. In the meantime, if you know the encoding that your network administrator used when they named the computer, tell your library to `decode('windows-1250')` instead (assuming that's the actual encoding you want to decode).

Comment: You might call it dubious advice but it was litterally how I had solved it myself.

Comment: Oh I'm sure it _works_ but yielding to the imperialist pressure is an unattractive workaround. We should be able to use any characters we choose in our private computer names.

Comment: thanks for your help, i have solved the problem! It was just because of the username...